# PyCharm cannot change the `*.pyx` wildcard to be associated to a different file type

Tags: pycharm, cython, jetbrains-ide, file-type, file-type-associations

I installed a user settings from [here](https://geoexamples.com/python/2017/04/20/pycharm-cython.html) to enable highlighting of Cython keywords and type highlighting in PyCharm. The user settings consist of "File Types" and "File Types (Scheme)" which overwrites the `*.pyx` wildcard as a "Cython files" file type.

Though now I am using PyCharm's Professional Edition's Cython text highlighting, I just reassigned the wildcard `*.pyx` to be include to the "Cython" file type from JetBrains. But each time I open up PyCharm, it resets the wildcard to be assigned to the "Cython files" which I do not want to happen. So I attempted to remove this "Cython files" file type but just couldn't find it under "Settings | Editor | File Types" after multiple checks.

Do you guys know how to remove this behavior that keeps resetting the wildcard back to the "Cython files" each time I open up or remove this "Cython files" extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. I suppose you can easily export your settings to a safe location, and then reset your entire PyCharm IDE settings config to default. Then finally you can import your previous settings but without the File Types and File Types (Scheme) selection.